# `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for `ReadAllBytes' error unity3d from CapturePanorma script

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm new to unity3d and i want to capture a 360 video  of my small game using the 360 capture panorama asset but i keep getting the error `System.IO.File` does not contain a definition for `ReadAllBytes` and then an array of errors:

```
    GUI Window tries to begin rendering while something else has not finished rendering!
    Either you have a recursive OnGUI rendering, or previous OnGUI did not clean up properly.
    InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
    System.Collections.Stack.Peek () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Stack.cs:321)
    UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:280)
    UnityEditor.DockArea.EndOffsetArea () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:425)
    UnityEditor.DockArea.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:348)
    ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing Repaint
    Aborting
    UnityEngine.GUILayoutGroup.GetNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:656)
    UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.BeginLayoutArea (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, System.Type layoutType) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:297)
    UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.DoBeginLayoutArea (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, System.Type layoutType) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:312)
    UnityEditor.EditorGUILayoutUtilityInternal.BeginLayoutArea (UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, System.Type LayoutType) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/EditorGUIInternal.cs:65)
    UnityEditor.DockArea.BeginOffsetArea (Rect screenRect, UnityEngine.GUIContent content, UnityEngine.GUIStyle style) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:431)
    UnityEditor.DockArea.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/DockArea.cs:323)
    device.IsInsideFrame()
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to call this from inside ongui?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really new to c# and I don't understand :/ I found the code from the 360 capture panorama asset i didn't write it myself..

Comment: Focus on `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for `ReadAllBytes'  i think the rest of the errors are fixed with a change in layout i made

Comment: I noticed it's an asset in the asset store, are you on a mac out of curiosity? Either way, try adding 'using System.IO.File;" at the top with your using statements.

Comment: try this - in Build Settings scroll down to the last tab and set Api Compatibility Level to .NET 2.0 (instead of .NET 2.0 Subset)

Comment: No i'm not a Mac user..I replaced using System.IO with using System.IO.FIle and it gives me the error System.IO.File' is a type not a namespace. A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces

Comment: @NikaKasradze I already did this but still it gave me the same error

Comment: In build settings, are you building against a PC, a web browser, a phone, etc?

If you aren't building against a PC, build against a PC and see what happens.

Comment: right now i'm not building anything i just added in the assets capture panorama and this error appears! :/

Comment: I know, but your build settings tell you what you're building against. If you're building against the web or a phone (if you created a project and select "Web" or "iPhone"), for instance, unity will only load up the proper code for that.

So if you're build settings are set to web, for instance, you won't get System.IO.File, and that error will appear. Go to File->Build Settings and switch to PC/Mac/Linux... if you aren't building against that.

Comment: ok I understand i switched platform to pc and the same error appears:  `System.IO.File' is a type not a namespace. A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces

Comment: Try switching it to "System.IO" instead of "System.IO.File"

Comment: ok now it's fixed!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just so you know why it happened, when you were in the web or phone build, System.IO was inaccessible and the error popped up thinking it was a type (like an int). When you were in the PC version, I told you to add File by mistake and it a type (File is a thing inside IO) so it failed. Just in case you ever try "using System.Datetime" or something.

Comment: ok I think I understand!! Thank you very much for being so informative!